# Post request works from postman but not from python

Tags: python, postman

When I run this script from postman it successfully posts to gettr, but when I run it in pycharm with the script postman gave me it gives me the error.

```
{"_t":"xresp","rc":"ERR","error":{"_t":"xerr","code":"E_RES_NOACCESS","emsg":"empty post","args":[]}}"
```

this is the same error code I get when I ran the code in postman but without the body form-data and no matter what I do I cant seem to fix it, I've tried renaming the payload, changing the max amount of characters on a line as I thought that may have been the issue, and json-encoding the payload.
The payload isn't being sent to the server, everything else is but the payload isn't and I can't figure out why.

here's the code I was given from postman

```
import requests

url = "https://api.gettr.com/u/post"

payload={'content': '{"data":{"udate":1627766410444,"acl":{"_t":"acl"},"_t":"post","cdate":1627766410444,"txt":"TEST2","uid":"nseruame2"},"aux":null,"serial":"post"}'}
files=[

]
headers = {
        'authority': 'api.gettr.com',
        'x-app-url': 'https://gettr.com',
        'enctype': 'multipart/form-data',
        'x-app-auth': '{"user":"nseruame2","token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJrZXkiOiJuc2VydWFtZTIiLCJsZXZlbCI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNjI3NzY1NTU3LCJleHAiOjE2MzI5NDk1NTd9.x5WfCL2ts9ZPRPfrXoRsx8Ht9_Qwvu8a6Z0LsST2c-Q"}',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.115 Safari/537.36',
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarylT5AFlKSBTmaMSRX',
        'sec-gpc': '1',
        'origin': 'https://gettr.com',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'referer': 'https://gettr.com/',
        'accept': '*/*',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

what am I doing wrong that's causing this error and how do I fix it.

E_RES_NOACCESS means it wasn't given an authentication token, the server isn't getting the payload as the error code says its missing all the key things that are stored in the payload.

Comment: Does that payload need to be JSON-encoded?  If so, you should use `json=payload`, not `data=payload`.

Comment: I suggest you review the API documentation to find out exactly what E_RES_NOACCESS means. My guess is that your x-app-auth token is invalid

Comment: I tried json-encoding the payload and that didn't work, same error code, it isn't sending the payload, its sending the files, and the headers, but not the payload, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Your “[mre]” doesn’t show the value you put in `files=files` - what does this look like? Have you traced the POST from postman and requests to see th deifferences using e.g. Telelrik Fiddler? Also, what http error code are you getting? Have you checked with Postman if your browser is sending auth cookies with the request (i.e. ones you’re not sending from Python)?

Comment: files=files is empty, Its also not being sent so I should probably get rid of it. However thanks for the comparing suggestion, I used http toolkit to see exactly what it was sending and compared it to what postman sends and I was right, it isn't sending the payload but it is sending everything else.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this isnt an answer but the issue is the request module cant send the content disposition to separate the payload, so the server is receiving the payload but not interpreting it correctly, I found I can just do this in node.js so I'm just gonna do that

Comment: This answer is marked as correct, yet fails to explain how to resolve the particular issue.